# Questions regarding projecting the energy-momentum tensor for perfect fluid along the four-velocity

Tags: general-relativity, vectors, tensor-calculus, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

The energy momentum tensor for a perfect fluid is defined as:

$$T^{\mu \nu} = (\rho + p)U^\mu U^\nu + p \eta^{\mu \nu}$$

Where $\rho$ is the energy density, $p$ is momentum, $U$ is the four-velocity (tangent vector parameterized by proper time), and $\eta$ is the Minkowski metric.

I've read:

> To project $\partial _ \mu T^{\mu \nu}$ along the four-velocity, simply contract it into $U_\nu$. $$U_\nu \partial_\mu T^{\mu \nu}$$

First of all, I believe $\partial_\mu T^{\mu \nu}$ has four components, where each component is the divergence of momentum multiplied by $U^\nu$. (This is the change in momentum flux in the $\nu$ direction?)

So, $U_\nu \partial_\mu T^{\mu \nu}$ is an inner-product between the four-velocity and the momentum-flux, which should result in a single number, correct?

Furthermore, I write a lot of notes in my textbook, and in trying to explain this, I find myself struggling when referring to parts of a tensor. For example, can I say something like "The second index of $T^{\mu \nu}$ represents the directional component of the tensor."

(I am struggling w/ tensors, so any detailed explanation is very much appreciated).

Answer (score 1):

Geometrically, the stress-energy-momentum tensor is the covector-valued 3-form
$$
T = T_{\mu\nu} \;\mathrm dx^\mu \otimes \star\mathrm dx^\nu
$$
where we have represented the 3-form part via Hodge duality (think normal vector).

This leads to several natural operations, eg integration over 3-surfaces of spacetime (yielding a 4-momentum covector), contraction with a 4-velocity  (yielding energy-momentum densities as measured in the corresponding frame), or exterior differentiation (think divergence, which can eg be used to generalize Newton's equations to relativistic continuum mechanics).

What the abstract expression $U_\nu\partial_\mu T^{\mu\nu}$ represents is the combination of the latter two operations, though that's only true under the assumption of a symmetric SEM tensor - by geometric reasoning, we should contract the derivatives with the second index:
$$
\mathrm dT = \partial_\lambda T_{\mu\nu}\; dx^\mu \otimes \mathrm dx^\lambda \wedge \star\mathrm dx^\nu = \eta^{\lambda\nu} \partial_\lambda T_{\mu\nu}\; dx^\mu \otimes \mathrm d^4x
$$

More pragmatically, the meaning of the individual components of the SEM tensor are

[image: SEM tensor components]

When we contract $\partial_\nu$ with the column index $\nu$ of $T^{\mu\nu}$ we get a continuity-equation style expression for each row indexed by $\mu$, ie
$$\text{time derivative of density} + \text{divergence of flux}$$

Contraction with $U_\mu$ will then project onto the time-like component (aka energy) as measured by an observer moving with 4-velocity $U^\mu$, ie
$$\text{time derivative of observed energy density} + \text{divergence of observed energy flux}$$

---

Not sure if it will help much, but here's a short explanation how the formalism works for people without a background in differential geometry:

The differentials $\mathrm dx^\mu$ are the basis vectors of momentum space. For example, the momentum of a particle is given by
$$
p = p_\mu\mathrm dx^\mu = E\,\mathrm dt + p_i\,\mathrm dx^i
$$

In continuum mechanics, we have to operate with spatial densities, so instead of, say, an energy $E$, we need an energy density $\epsilon\,\mathrm dV$.

Naively, the generalization of the momentum 4-vector to continuum mechanics would then be something like
$$
\rho_\mu\,\mathrm dx^\mu\otimes\mathrm dV
$$
where $\rho_0=\epsilon$ is our energy density and $\rho_i$ are the spatial momentum densities.<sup>1</sup>

Such an expression should make a relativist's alarm bells ring, because where there's a
$$
\mathrm dV = \mathrm dx\wedge\mathrm dy\wedge\mathrm dz
$$
we also expect
$$
\mathrm dt\wedge\mathrm dx\wedge\mathrm dy \qquad
\mathrm dt\wedge\mathrm dy\wedge\mathrm dz \qquad
\mathrm dt\wedge\mathrm dz\wedge\mathrm dx
$$
to show up.

The correct generalization of the 4-momentum turns out to be the SEM tensor, whose first index labels the directions of momentum space, and its second one the above volume elements.

Finally, for convenience, the [Hodge star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_dual) can be used to represent the volume elements of the 3-dimensional hyperplanes by their normal vectors, eg
$$
\star\mathrm dt = \mathrm dx\wedge\mathrm dy\wedge\mathrm dz
$$

---

<sup>1</sup> and that's indeed the first column of the SEM tensor

Comment: Thanks for the explanation (the picture and that below it was helpful), but I'm afraid a lot of what you wrote is lost on me.

Comment: @AmagicalFishy: I added some parapraphs that might or might not be helpful to you...